# List Max Date for duplicate rows in a Column - Google Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a data range imported from another sheet that contains an ID, Name & StartDate Columns:
e.g.

```
+------+------+-------------+
| ID   | Name | StartDate   |
+------+------+-------------+
| 1001 | abc  | 11/10/2020  |
+------+------+-------------+
| 1001 | def  | 12/12/2020  |
+------+------+-------------+
| 1002 | ghi  | 04/06/2020  |
+------+------+-------------+
| 1003 | jkl  | 11/08/2020  |
+------+------+-------------+
| 1003 | mno  | 06/02/2020  |
+------+------+-------------+
| 1004 | pqr  | 11/02/2020  |
+------+------+-------------+
| 1004 | stu  | 11/21/2020  |
+------+------+-------------+
```

into

```
+------+------+-------------+
| ID   | Name | StartDate   |
+------+------+-------------+
| 1001 | def  | 12/12/2020  |
+------+------+-------------+
| 1002 | ghi  | 04/06/2020  |
+------+------+-------------+
| 1003 | jkl  | 11/08/2020  |
+------+------+-------------+
| 1004 | stu  | 11/21/2020  |
+------+------+-------------+
```

and i want to find the maximum date for any duplicate ID rows and list the corresponding Name and max StartDate, how is this possible in Google Query?

tried:

```
=QUERY(J:L,"select J,K,MAX(L) where J is not null group by J,K label MAX(L)'StartDate'")
```

but still get duplicates i.e. same range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A2:C, 3, ), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:C,COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,C:C,">"&C:C)},"select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col4=0"))
```

(The previous is updated from the original answer I posted when I did not totally understand the goal.)

Comment: already had tried this but still getting duplicates. My range is in J to L. Here is the query `=QUERY(J:L,"select J,K,MAX(L) where J is not null group by J,K label MAX(L)'StartDate'")`

Comment: @sifar tough to figure out why that would be without a sample sheet.  Could you share a link to a sample sheet?

Comment: Sure. [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qHBryHm7CLAxhykhJVEwbPZbrOAKCd5qgbxWYUUb5t0/edit?usp=sharing] (Sample Sheet)

Comment: @sifar you're right, I misunderstood.  I've updated with this new formula:
=FILTER(A2:C,NOT(COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,ROW(A2:A),">"&ROW(A2:A))))

Comment: so it is not possible with google query? BTW, the formula gives me incorrect result (minimum date) for `1003`.

Comment: @sifar hmm, could you make your shared sheet editable instead of view only so i can demo and test there?  Could be possible with query, but in combination with a vlookup.

Comment: Does this mean Google Query is not the right choice to get the result? In SQL, it would be a straight forward answer.

Comment: Can you update your answer in your solution, for future reference? That was one ingenious answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: One problem i see, is that if the dates are same, then both get listed. Any tiebreaker that can be implemented to just have the sorted last name and its date?